# Custom gradient in tensorflow attempts to convert model to tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use the output of one neural network to compute the loss value for another network. As the first network is approximating another function (L2 distance) I would like to provide the gradients myself, as if it had come from an L2 function.

An example of my loss function in simplified code is:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def loss_function(model_1_output):

    def grad(dy, variables=None):
        gradients = 2 * pred
        return gradients

    pred = model_2(model_1_output)
    loss = pred ** 2
    return loss, grad
```

This is called in a standard tensorflow 2.0 custom training loop such as:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

    model_1_output = model_1(training_data)
    loss = loss_function(model_1_output)

gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model_1.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables)
```

However, whenever I try to run this I keep getting the error:

`ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<model.model_2 object at 0x7f41982e3240>) with an unsupported type (<class 'model.model_2'>) to a Tensor.`

The whole point of using the `custom_gradients` decorator is that I don't want the `model_2` in the loss function to be included in the back propagation as I give it the gradients manually.

How can I make tensorflow completely ignore anything inside the loss function? So that for example I could do non-differetiable operations. I have tried using `with tape.stop_recording()` but I always result in a no gradients found error.

Using:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 
tensorflow: 2.0.0
python: 3.7
```

Comment: You should probably check how to use `GradientTape` you can calculate the gradients of whatever you need. Check for an example my notebook here https://github.com/michelucci/oreilly-london-ai/blob/master/day1/Polynomial%20fitting%20with%20TF1%20and%20TF2/Polynomial_fitting_with_eager_execution_TF2_X.ipynb. First you use a context `with tf.GradientTape() as t:` and then in the context you can do the operations you need to track, and then you can calculate the gradients 'gradients = t.gradient(loss_value, trainable_variables)'. Check if that helps you,.

Comment: I have this in my code above. I understand how to use the gradient tape for conventional purposes. I am struggling with the fact the gradient tape is automatically trying to convert everything in the loss function to a tensor. I effectively want to hide anything that happens in the loss function from the tape and just supply the gradients myself.